# Is there a good algorithm for the minimal computation of a CNF without extra variables?

Tags: database, logic, z3, boolean-logic

I'm currently working on tranforming logical queries for database systems from a DNF form into a CNF form, focussed on queries which have a similar form to
`(a and b and c and d and e1) or (a and b and c and d and e2) or (a and b and c and d and e3)`,
into
`a and b and c and d and (e1 or e2 or e3)`

I expected there to already be an algorithm for that, but I am currently working with z3 and the only way to form a CNF out of that I saw was with tseitin or similar, which includes extra variables, which are a problem as they can't be used for queries properly.

Comment: You can, but the translation can produce exponentially larger formulas. But perhaps that’s not a big deal if your examples are small enough to start with.

Comment: It was mainly to use for formulas similar to the example, with large logical overlap of the different parts. The problem I have is reducing the size at runtime, so as to not compute everything at once but reducing the amount of options computed.

Comment: Let the SAT/SMT solver do its job. Don't worry about "computing everything." The whole point of the SAT/SMT search is to do smart-search to get you a satisfiable set. Unless you're observing huge slow-downs, I wouldn't worry about this at all. (And if you do, then you should post an example query that gives you hard time.)

Comment: I need this for a database system. In which it is useless for me to find one satisfiable set. I need a conjunct formula I can split and push down the query graph.

Comment: So, you're using z3 to convert dnf to cnf? Not any actual solving?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I am open for suggestions if there is anything better I can use.

Answer (score 0):

Using z3 for this purpose is probably not the best option. While there's an internal converter, it's tuned to be used in conjunction with the rest of the solver. If you don't have a need to find a satisfying model, you shouldn't be using a SAT/SMT solver.

Conversion from DNF to CNF can produce exponentially large formulas, and this is the reason why most practical applications will use [Tseytin transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tseytin_transformation) to reduce this complexity; which adds extra variables. If you don't want this, you should use the [Quine-McCluskey algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quine%E2%80%93McCluskey_algorithm), which has worst case exponential behavior. But if your formulas are small enough to start with, it may not matter.

You can code this algorithm yourself, or if you're open to using SymPy, there's an existing implementation (with possible simplifications). See https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/logic.html?highlight=to_cnf#sympy.logic.boolalg.to_cnf

Comment: I don't think that is what I am looking for. Ideally the algorithm I need shouldn't take this long, but be more linear with my example. E.g. in my example even if I add f, g, h, ..., z and so on to the three clauses, it should only grow polynomial with the amount of variables. (I think in this case it might even be able to work in linear time).

Comment: General CNF conversion is expensive. But if your input is of a certain style, it might work faster. Note that this doesn't change the algorithm you should use: You'll just be using it where it works well.